# How to Bring the Widget Bring to front in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Please have a look at this screenshot:

[image]

The circles are custom controls. When I click a control, I need to bring the widget to the front. Ex. if I click the second circle it should look like this:

[image]

When the control is clicked I am able to get the sender (i.e. the control). Only thing is how to bring the object to the front.

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Could you specify what type are your circles? And what type is the zone in which you are painting them?

Answer (score 69):

Have you tried [QWidget::raise()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#raise)?

> Raises this widget to the top of the parent widget's stack.  After this call the widget will be visually in front of any overlapping sibling widgets.
>   Note: When using activateWindow(), you can call this function to ensure that the window is stacked on top.

So the pattern I usually use that will ensure a window is shown, brought to the front of sibling widgets and brought in front of other applications is:

```
widget->show();
widget->activateWindow();
widget->raise();
```