# How to QDialog raise() function is not working?

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow, qdialog

From my QMainwindow I am opening a second QDialog window when a pushbutton is pressed.This is my code

> ```
>     newFile = new Dialog();  
>     if(fStatus == 0)
>     {
>         newFile.show();
>         fStatus = 1;
>     }
>
>     else if(fStatus == 1)
>     {
>         newFile.raise();
>     }
> ```

What I am trying to do is if the QDialog window is already open and the push button is pressed again I want my QDialog window to move to front.

I have tried same with Qwidget form it is working but Qdialog raise(); is not working,but in case of Qwidget I am not able not capture the Qwidget destroyed signal on closing of the widow properly.

Comment: What happens if you set the window as the parent of dialog?

Comment: Please provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5):

I didn't tested it but from what I read I found this :

```
yourQWidget->show();
yourQWidget->activateWindow();
yourQWidget->raise();
```

[How to Bring the Widget Bring to front in QT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821743/how-to-bring-the-widget-bring-to-front-in-qt)

```
QDialog *yourQDialog = new ...
yourQDialog->setWindowFlags(yourQDialog->windowFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
yourQDialog->show();
```

[Bring QDialog to front](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/13175-Bring-QDialog-to-front)

Also loook at this question: [Bring window to front -> raise(),show(),activateWindow() don’t work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087887/bring-window-to-front-raise-show-activatewindow-don-t-work)

Comment: yourQDialog->setWindowFlags(yourQDialog->windowFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint); This line was the key for me. I literally spent hours fixing this problem. Thanks!!!

Comment: @edusan1213 i have no idea what's there anymore, since 2017 i didn't work with Qt, but glad it helped :D