# How to bring widget to front using stylesheets in PyQt?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtstylesheets

How can you bring a widget to the front using PyQt stylesheets? To [bring a widget to the front programmically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821743/how-to-bring-the-widget-bring-to-front-in-qt), you can use [QWidget::raise()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#raise) which

> Raises the widget to the top of the parent widget's stack. After this call the widget will be visually in front of any overlapping sibling widgets.

How can I get the same effect using stylesheets? Is there a CSS equivalent of [`z-index`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) in PyQt?

For instance

```
QTabBar::tab:bottom {
    color: #F0F0F0;
    border-top: 3px solid #32414B;
    background-color: #32414B;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

But I get this error:

> Unknown property z-index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

**TL; DR:**

Not all CSS properties are supported by Qt Style Sheet. In the following [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties) are all the properties available by Qt Style Sheets

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc. Learned a lot from you